# Understanding `var status = (string: statusVal as NSString)` variable declaration in Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsstring

I found the following code in a project that compiles and executes successfully. But I am unable to understand how it works. I tried Googling it using a variety of search phrases but couldn't find an explanation.

```
let statusVal = "Somestring"
var status = (string: statusVal as NSString)
```

Can someone clarify what is going on in the second line ? 
According to what little knowledge I have in Swift , the second line should be something like

```
var status = NSString(string: statusVal as NSString)
```

which of course compiles as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While,it is just a **tuple** with one element

```
var status = (abcdefg:"abc")
```

The part `abcdefg` is description, and "abc" is value.

If a tuple has only one element,it used the type of the element.So the type of status is `String`

More document about tuple
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: Ah yes,  I guess that would classify as a tuple with 1 element,  I would never think to make a tuple with 1 element, so that never crossed my mind haha

Answer (score 2):

What is really happening is `var status = statusVal as NSString`,  the `string:` part is just giving the variable an association,  which is ignored when the code is executed.  You can put any word you want in place of `string:` and the code will still compile.

Comment: Thanks @KnightOfDragon. Can you point me to some documentation that explains this. I am still learning Swift and unfamiliar with many of it's nuances :)

Comment: I tried your suggestion in playground and it works. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know what it would even be called in documentation,  I just know that is what it is doing

Comment: as Leo has pointed out,  it is a tuple with 1 element that consists of a description ( I said association) and value

Comment: Yeah, Leo mentioning it is a tuple clarified what is going on.